# Newb ObjC Question re: BOOL property on a class

Tags: iphone, objective-c

@interface...

```
BOOL nameIsValid;

@property (nonatomic) BOOL nameIsValid;
```

@implementation...

```
@sysnthesize nameIsValid;

-(void)someMethod {
    nameIsValid = YES;
}

-(void)anotherMethod {
    if(nameIsValid){
       ...
    }
}
```

Why does my if statement always evaluate to FALSE, even after the someMethod is called?

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.propertyName = value`, instead.

Why: Using the `self` prefix with a left-hand side property calls its synthesized setter method.

If you don't use the setter, then the default value of the `BOOL` will remain `NO` (or `0`).

Comment: Thanks, but that made no difference.  Is there anything else that could be wrong?